# how to return to original destination after intercept in Grails controller

Tags: grails, intercept

Greetings!
I have an intercept in controller like so:

```
    def beforeInterceptor = {

    if( session.sessionRoastId == null ){

        session.intendedController = params.controller
        session.intendedAction = params.action

        redirect( controller: 'roastId', action: 'enterRoastId' )
        return false
    }
}
```

... after the redirect business is taken care of, what's proper way to continue on to the original controller action and view that the intercept picked up?

Right now I'm putting the details in the session to be accessed later down the road, but is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the original target URI as a parameter to the 'enterRoastId' action, and then redirect there.

```
def beforeInterceptor = {
    if( session.sessionRoastId == null ){
        redirect( controller: 'roastId', action: 'enterRoastId', params: [
            action: params.action, 
            controller: params.controller
        ])
        return false
    }
}
```

then in your action AFTER enterRoastId:

```
if (params.action && params.controller) {
    redirect(controller: params.controller, action: params.action)
    return false
}
```

If you don't want to expose the action/controller, then just pass the values to the 'enterRoastId' view, and pass them back via a hidden field.

Comment: ... that would work as well, thanks :-) Neither hiding nor exposing are factors in this case so either way would work.